# alguem consegue ajudar com essa mensagem aqui Failed to locate or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider?

Tags: c#, winforms, firebird

Eu criei um aplicativo com Windows forms conectando-se ao firebird, onde na minha máquina de desenvolvimento tudo funciona perfeitamente, mas quando eu coloco na máquina cliente, o seguinte erro ocorre:

> ```
> System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed.          
>     at System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory (String providerInvariantName)  
>     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.TryInitializeFromAppConfig (String name)  
>     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.Initialize ()  
>     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalConnection.get_ConnectionHasModel ()  
>     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext ()  
>     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType (Type entityType)  
>     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize ()  
>     at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext ()  
>     at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider ()  
>     at System.Linq.Queryable.Where [TSource] (IQueryable`1 source, Expression`1 predicate)  
>     at Infrastructure.Data.Seedwork.Repository`1.GetFiltered (Expression`1 filter)  
>     at SanNuvens.SpedEFD.FrmGeraSped.FrmGeraSped_Load (Object sender, EventArgs e)  
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad (EventArgs and)  
>     at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl ()
> ```

Comment: como está seu app.config ?

Comment: <configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MainBCUnitOfWork" connectionString="Server=192.168.7.162;User=SYSDBA;Password=a123456;Database=C:\Gerencial\Sans\Banco\geral.fdb;Port=3050;Dialect=3;Charset=ISO8859_1" providerName="FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient"/>
  
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: na máquina cliente, está levando a biblioteca que contém o provider `FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient` ?

Comment: então Rovann la na pasta do cliente junto com as dll necessárias a FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll esta lá também...

Comment: no seu app.config do cliente, a `dll` está registrada na seção `<system.data>`?

Comment: Ricardo Pontual desculpa a demora e obrigado pela atenção, me desculpe mas não compreendi a sua pergunta, e como eu faria isso ??

Answer (score 0):

tive que adicionar no arquivo machine.config que fica C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\versao\Config as seguintes linhas

em ConfigSection

e em